# Applying a background for the control in an Effect in XamarinForms

Tags: xamarin.forms, uwp, background, effects, acrylic-material

I'm trying to apply a background for what ever the control the effect is attached to.

First i made the effect to apply a background for the controls that have either a Fill or Background properties in UWP. 
But the problem is a lot of controls renderes to FrameworkElement in UWP. And FrameworkElement doesn't have a Background property .
In the VisualElementRenderer Xamarin forms adresses this issue be applying a background layer behind the content but this is an effect.
Is there is any way to apply a background for whatever the effect is attached to? 
I'm appplying an AcrylicBrush So it must be assigned to the Control directly.

The code i written before:

```
try
{
   Control.GetType().GetProperty("Background").SetValue(Control, brush);
}
catch
{
   Control.GetType().GetProperty("Fill").SetValue(Control, brush);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm appplying an AcrylicBrush So it must be assigned to the Control directly.

You could use `compositor` to apply Acrylic to `SpriteVisual`. We use [Win2D](https://microsoft.github.io/Win2D/html/Introduction.htm) to make `GaussianBlurEffect` for `UIElement` before we have [Acrylic API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.media.acrylicbrush). Get `Compositor` of UIElement, and use this `Compositor` to `CreateSpriteVisual`. then set `GaussianBlurEffect` to `hostSprite.Brush` like the following.

```
Compositor _compositor;
SpriteVisual _hostSprite;

private void applyAcrylicAccent(Panel panel)
{
    _compositor = ElementCompositionPreview.GetElementVisual(panel).Compositor;
    _hostSprite = _compositor.CreateSpriteVisual();
    _hostSprite.Size = new Vector2((float)panel.ActualWidth, (float)panel.ActualHeight);

    var backdrop = _compositor.CreateHostBackdropBrush();

    // Use a Win2D blur affect applied to a CompositionBackdropBrush.
    var graphicsEffect = new GaussianBlurEffect
    {
        Name = "Blur",
        BlurAmount = 100f,
        Source = new CompositionEffectSourceParameter("backdrop")
    };

    var effectFactory = Window.Current.Compositor.CreateEffectFactory(graphicsEffect, new[] { "Blur.BlurAmount" });
    var effectBrush = effectFactory.CreateBrush();

    effectBrush.SetSourceParameter("backdrop", backdrop);
    _hostSprite.Brush = effectBrush;

    ElementCompositionPreview.SetElementChildVisual(panel, _hostSprite);
}
```

And calling it with applyAcrylicAccent(RootLayout). You also will need to handle the `SizeChanged` event :

```
private void LayoutRoot_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (_hostSprite != null)
        _hostSprite.Size = e.NewSize.ToVector2();
}
```

[image]

Comment: But the AcrylicBrush doesn't apply just a gaussian blur.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/style/images/acrylicrecipe_diagram.jpg

Comment: Yep, but you could not  modify it directly except for other properties of the Gaussian property.